# ng-class with ng-repeat in component, data is not binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I actually have this repeater (Angular 1.5, not 2) :

```
<article ng-repeat='item in $ctrl.items' ng-class="{ 'content_large' : item.large_size }" >

    <div>{{item.something}}</div>

</article>
```

The `ng-class` is not working (no class applied).

`item.large_size` is a `boolean` (no string).

This loop is in a custom component which is in a view. Some data's (items) is bind from the view to the component (its working fine). I'm getting the data in the component with `$ctrl.items`. The data binding in children (`item.something)` is working fine and if I move the `ng-class` to the children, he's working too.

I saw that when the data is not coming from the parent the ng-class should work. So I think it's because it's a custom component. The way the data is bind is doing something.

Here is the produced HTML :

```
<!-- ngRepeat: item in $ctrl.items -->
<article ng-repeat='item in $ctrl.items' ng-class="{ 'content_large' : item.large_size }">
    <div>Something</div>
</article>
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in $ctrl.items -->
<article ng-repeat='item in $ctrl.items' ng-class="{ 'content_large' : item.large_size }">
    <div>Something</div>
</article>
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in $ctrl.items -->
```

So, no class added :(

What is the solution ?
Thanks.

Comment: check for `item.large_size ` is exist or not?

Comment: Are you using the `transclude` option in the directive? Can you show an eample of the HTML that it is producing?

Comment: @R.J
I tried to add a class like this `class="{{ item.large_size }}"` on the article and it's working, I got the class true or false on the element.
@SunilD. no i'm not using it.

Comment: @SunilD. I edited the post to add an exemple of the HTML :)